# AWS SES : Basic python code to send a csv file to email

Tags: python, amazon-ses

Can someone share a basic python code to send a csv file to email id like abc@gmail.com using AWS SES Service

I know this can be done via AWS SES Service, But I didn't find anyone sharing Python code as all around I found Java Code

Comment: you couldnt find *any* code? I find that hard to believe..

Comment: Perhaps you could try to write the code yourself instead of copying it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a python example in the [AWS Code Examples library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/ses_example_cross_RDSDataTracker_section.html) that uses SES to send a CSV attachment. It is part of a library of examples maintained by AWS:

> The report.py file contains functions that send an email report of work items to a specified email address.

> When 10 or fewer work items are included in the report, the work item list is included directly in the email body, with both HTML and text versions. This style of report is sent by using the send_email service action, which lets you send the HTML and text body as plain Python strings.

> When the list is larger than 10 work items, it is rendered in CSV format and included as an attachment to the email. When you use Amazon SES to send an attachment, you must use the send_raw_email service action and send the email in MIME format.

The code can be found in this [repository in report.py](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/python/cross_service/aurora_item_tracker/report.py), and the relevant [README is also pretty descriptive](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/python/cross_service/aurora_item_tracker).

You should be able to clone the repository and follow the instructions to run the example on the command line.